# Download files from a google cloud computer engine to a local directory

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, sftp, gcloud, scp

Hi I'm trying to download files in a certain directory (called `zipcy`) from google cloud VM to my local machine BUT when I ran the code `gcloud compute scp --recurse instance-zipcy:zipcy ~/Downloads`, it doesn't download files to my local machine but create `Downloads` directory inside this google cloud VM (image attached) I spent a whole day but couldn't solve...

Also, I saw some suggested

`scp -r username@server:/path/to/your/directory /local/destination`

Here, is it correct that server should be the external IP address and username should be `julia` or the name of this instance? (Image attached)

If I have to use `sftp` instead of `scp` creating SSH key pairs is necessary?

I'm new to this so any helps or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjxO3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're likely stumbling over the format of the arguments for this command.

Essentially you need to provide it 3 things:

1. An instance (and possibly a project) to use
2. A source location (the files to be copied)
3. A destionation location (the location to copy the files)

Here's the documentation for [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)

I assume (!) you're using Linux.

Let's use an example:

We'll create a file (`test`) on the host in your home directory:

```bash
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]
INSTANCE=[YOUR-INSTANCE-NAME]

# Check your gcloud account
gcloud config get account

# SSH into the instance
gcloud compute ssh ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Check your user
# This should mirror your gcloud account {whoami}@email.com
whoami

# Check the home directory
# This should be /home/{whoami}
pwd

# Create a dummy file
touch test

# Exit from SSH
exit
```

Now, we'll `scp` that file to your host's `Downloads` folder:

```bash
gcloud compute scp \
  ${INSTANCE}:test \
  ${HOME}/Downloads \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

You should see the file is copied successful and you can then:

```bash
ls -la ${HOME}/Downloads/test
```

The `gcloud compute scp` command uses `${PROJECT}` (your project).

It copies **from** (the source) `${INSTANCE}` (your instance name) working directory (i.e. `/home/$(whoami)` (but you don't need to specify this) the `test` file.

It copies **to** (the destination), your host's (!) `${HOME}/Downloads` directory.

The command is equivalent to:

```bash
gcloud compute scp \
  ${INSTANCE}:/home/$(whoami)/test \
  ${HOME}/Downloads \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

You *may* have issues copying files from a remote host **if** you are not the owner of the files. For example, if the files are owned by `root`. In this case, you can try copying the files elsewhere on the remote instance (!), using `chown` to change their ownership and then specifying the copy (!) when you use `gcloud compute scp`.